# NavigationView вытягивание шторки

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation

Создал я NavigationView и не могу никак найти, как сделать так, чтобы при свайпе(в правильную сторону) всегда появлялась эта шторка, а ни только при свайпе со стороны, где она находится.Вобщем хочу сделать как в Телеграмме.

Может, кто знает специальный метод или атрибут в XML?

Comment: Задача не очень понятна. Вы ведь про NavigationDrawer говорите? Если да, то непонятно при чём тут телеграм - только что проверил - NavigationView там только слева появляется.

Comment: Я к тому что по умолчанию, что бы вытянуть его слева, надо чуть бы не на левую границу экрана нажать и делать свайп, в то время как, в телеграмме при свайпе откуда угодно(слева на права) покажется меню

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877797/open-navigationview-on-right-swipe-from-everywhere-on-the-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 fun openDrawer() {
        val mDragger = javaClass.superclass?.getDeclaredField("mLeftDragger")
        mDragger?.isAccessible = true
        val draggerObj = mDragger!!.get(this) as ViewDragHelper
 
        val mEdgeSize = draggerObj.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mEdgeSize")
        mEdgeSize.isAccessible = true
        val edge = mEdgeSize.getInt(draggerObj)
 
        Log.i("Drawer","Edge ${edge}")
        mEdgeSize.setInt(draggerObj, edge * edge)
    }
```